# flutter Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111

Tags: flutter, websocket

iam tring to use web sockets

and it's working fine on the others devices and on also release mood

but my emulator , simulator and real device not working on it and always give me this error

```
Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = "my website url" port = 49718
```

thank you

Comment: Please add internet permission and check your internet is on

Comment: Where is the server? On your computer? Is it localhost?

Comment: its not localhost , and the server is online i mean its the production url and the user using the app and it works for the users but not works for me